# Why does DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$( readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" )" && pwd )" return "no such file or directory" when calling ${DIR}?

Tags: bash, unix

I am currently trying to find the full directory name of a script I am calling. I found code online that uses:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$( readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" )" && pwd )"
```

to set the directory, then afterwards, I try to open a file by calling:

```
open ${DIR}/file_open.jpg
```

to which I get `-bash: /Volumes/Drive: No such file or directory`. I am unsure why this doesn't work. I am running it from Mac OSX's terminal. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Always quote your variables: `open "$DIR"...`

Comment: Do you use `\"` for your inner quotes ?

Comment: @albttx not when nesting `$(`...`)`.  Quotes inside are automatically at a separate level from quotes outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't quote your variable.

```
open "${DIR}/file_open.jpg"
```

You must quote it. See [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) why quoting is important.

Also DIR is simpler as:

```
DIR=$(dirname "$(readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")
```